# Resolution for the double "the" problem

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech, determiners

Consider the following sentence:

> *With the Nike shirt, your workout will be complete.*

How will I say the same thing about a shirt of the brand *'The North Face'*?

The least awkward option will probably be:

> *With The North Face shirt, your workout will be complete.*

...which comes off as incomplete, since it's grammatically equivalent to:

> *With Nike shirt, your workout will be complete.*

Is the word "the" playing two roles here (a determiner **and** a part of an adjective phrase)?

Is a single word occurrence even allowed to have two part-of-speech categories?

Comment: It should be: "With the North Face shirt, your workout will be complete" (notice I dropped the capital on 'the').

Comment: @Silenus, being a part of a brand's name, doesn't "the" have to be capitalized? when looking on your proposal, it looks as if you reduced the brand name to "North Face" and "the" is merely a determiner

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and it's standard practice, although I can't cite anything (I'll leave that to someone else). Notice that when names include the definite article, we even sometimes *omit* the article; For example: "I love Lord of the Rings merchandise" (even though the correct title of the franchise is *The Lord of the Rings*).

Comment: You would never say "I bought a The North Face shirt." You'd say "I bought a North Face shirt." The indefinite article "a" helps to illustrate the convention.

Comment: @Silenus, your point is well taken. it can also resolve the part-of-speech conflict.

Comment: @Phil Sweet, i'm sure there are plenty of ways to express the same idea, but am trying to wrap my head around this particular sentence

Comment: Personally, I would cheat and reword the sentence: "With a shirt from The North Face, your workout will be complete."  I realize that doesn't answer your question from a theoretical standpoint, but it may solve it in practical terms.

Comment: Chicago Manual of Style recommends "dropping of the article [from a name] when it is grammatically convenient" (see the first answer here: http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/CapitalizationTitles.html?page=1).

Comment: @Silenus Although I usually dislike answers from single style guides, I think that dropping the 'the' from names beginning with one, when using the names attributively, is virtually universal.  Though I'd steer clear of 'The One soundtrack', opting for 'The soundtrack of "The One" '.

Comment: No idea what you would do if the shirt you needed was from [The The](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_The)

Comment: @DJClayworth Oddly enough, that’s one of the few places where I’d expect both articles to be kept in: “With the The The t-shirt…”.